# Rails inherit column in has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im quite new to rails and stumpled upon a challenge..

I have 3 models, user, skill and user_skill.

UserModel

```
has_many :user_skills
has_many :skills, :through => :user_skills
```

UserSkillModel

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :skill
```

SkillModel

```
has_many :user_skills
has_many :users, :through => :user_skills
```

In my UserSkill i have a column called level, so the idea is that when i assign a user a skill i can define a skill level. The whole association setup is working as far as i can tell, but im not sure how i get the level associated with the @user.skills result.

```
attributes: 
  id: 1
  name: Rails
  created_at: 
  updated_at:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a nice solution for your problem:

```
class UserSkill
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill

  delegate :name, :to => :skill
end
```

example:

```
@user_skills = @user.user_skills(:include => :skill).all

@user_skills.each do |user_skill|
  user_skill.name
  user_skill.level
end
```

Comment: delegate method in ActiveRecord, like the name suggest delegates method to another object. http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can go about it:

```
@user.user_skills.each do |user_skill|
  skill_name = user_skill.skill.name
  level = user_skill.level
end
```

This will get you the name of the skill and the level of the skill for each skill the user has.

If you have a user and a skill and want to find the level you can create a user function

```
def skill_level(skill)
  self.user_skills.find_by_skill(skill).level
end
```

then just call

```
@user.skill_level(skill)
```